# Base URL is not bringing Login Page in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, url, routes, angular-ui-router

I want to show login page in base url. Currently I am working in local dev so I want to open Login.html whenever I enter "http://localhost:xxxx" in address bar.

**Views/index.html**

I have used following here:-

```
<base href="/">
```

**RouteMainController.js**

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider       
        .state('login', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'mainview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Views/Login.html',
                    controller: 'ctrlLogin'
                }
            }
        })        
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

Login Page is coming as expected when I write following in Address Bar:-
http://localhost:50578/Views/index.html.

However when I write following in Address Bar:-
http://localhost:50578/
Then it is giving me following error:-

[image]

Enabling directory browsing did not help because it opens up the folder structure on doing so.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a series of investigation I corrected following things to make it work properly:-

- index.html was under "Views" folder. I put it outside and make it at root level.
- In web.config I made the following change:-

**Earlier:-**

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/Views/" />
```

**Changed To**

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
```

Hope this solution will help.